# Blob or BYTEA from Plain SQL Query in Slick 3.0.0

Tags: scala, jdbc, slick

I am trying to return a BLOB from a Postgres 9.4 database using Slick 3.0.0

My simple attempt is

`import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
import slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.Database
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`

```
object QueryRunner extends  App {
val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test","test_migration","test_migration",driver = "org.postgresql.Driver")

def selectRegions = sql"Select region_data from test.regions".as[java.sql.Blob]
val result = db.run(selectRegions)
val regionData = Await.result(result,1.seconds)}
```

That returns me

Error:(16, 65) could not find implicit value for parameter rconv: slick.jdbc.GetResult[java.sql.Blob]
  def selectRegions = sql"Select region_data from core.regions".as[java.sql.Blob]

I feel as though since Blob and BYTEA are somewhat specialized that I must be missing an import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slick's standard Postgres driver does not currently support Blobs, as well as many other Postgres-specific types.  See http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.0-M1/schemas.html:

> The following primitive types are supported out of the box for
> JDBC-based databases in JdbcProfile (with certain limitations imposed
> by the individual database drivers):
>
> Numeric types: Byte, Short, Int, Long, BigDecimal, Float, Double
>
> LOB types: java.sql.Blob, java.sql.Clob, Array[Byte]
>
> Date types: java.sql.Date, java.sql.Time, java.sql.Timestamp
>
> Boolean
>
> String
>
> Unit
>
> java.util.UUID

There has been a community effort to add support for additional types in a modified Postgres driver. You can monitor the results of that effort: https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg.

Comment: That is correct. I raised an issue where this particular matter is discussed. https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/issues/177

Comment: for a workaround see https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/97